# How to create standalone application for cross-compiled Qt for wince?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-ce, configure, cross-compiling

I followed this link to cross compile Qt for wince.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/install-wince.html
Everything worked as link says. I am able to run the applications on Visual Studio emulator for wince.
Now how do I make a single executable that can run on wince based device?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to go:

1- Compile everything in your program statically (static linking).

2- Use UPX to compress everything in one file, which will decompress and open automatically.
http://upx.sourceforge.net/

Just be aware of the licensing problems in Qt if you use static linking with Qt.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. So I have to build Qt statically..I mean with '-static' option for configure..??

Comment: Here's a tutorial about that. I'm going to update it to be fully independent with static linking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932315/how-to-compile-qt-5-static-or-dynamic-on-vs2010-or-vs2012-express-under-windows/14932316#14932316