# Deploying an app in QT and its perks

Tags: c++, qt, static-linking, dynamic-linking

You have your GUI application, filling all the list of requirements that the client has requested. All work is set and done, finally it is time to deploy. You promise to your client it won't take long now...

Except... Except that I have been postponing the deploy for the last two weeks trying to accomplish this task, but I couldn't imagine the nightmare it would be to finish the project and release it for the client.

So I have gone through the poor Qt 5.7 Documentation on how to deploy the project, I have tried to build Qt statically with no success, I am trying to dynamically link it but with no success.

I would appreciate the help from some experienced user who could help me step-by-step to either build it statically or dynamically and be able to release the project.

Basically, for my static build, I have tried the following:

1. ./configure -static -prefix=PATH
2. make
3. make install

Then I believe I should have a *.a file from here somewhere, but it doesn't happen so far. It takes a hell of a time, but no output can be observed in the working directory.

For dynamically linking, I have gone through ldd appname, copied all the listed libraries to a folder, but now I am running through the issue of building it dynamically with the entire list of dependencies and having them visible for my project (using qtcreator here too, which is making if even more messy for me).

So, as for now, I am lost and running out of time in order to achieve what was supposed to be not such a complicated task. I accept any recommendation that allows me **to distribute the project to the client, without having to worry if the client has all dependencies installed.**

Comment: Here is a good guide to building statically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932315/how-to-compile-qt-5-under-windows-or-linux-32-or-64-bit-static-or-dynamic-on-v