# error in static linking with qt in window 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I wanted to do static linking of Qt libraries to my project. I've done some tutorial (I downloaded source version of qt and then write a configure line in VS command prompt, I build everything by jom.exe). But apparently it works only with 32 bit versions of project. I want to make it work on 64 bit.
Error is in the line:
`Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QWindowsIntegrationPlugin)`

and it's says:

`qwindows.lib(main.obj) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'`
any ideas how to build it on x64 machine beacause I cannot find any useful information for this problem.

Comment: I tried to do this like this `configure -debug-and-release -opensource -platform win64-msvc2015` or with `msvc2010` but I get error mesage in VS cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a conflict between 32 and 64 bit libraries.

[Here's a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932315/how-to-compile-qt-5-under-windows-or-linux-32-or-64-bit-static-or-dynamic-on-v/14932316#14932316) on how to build Qt statically for 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can not link a Win32 library to 64 bit projects,