# How to configure Qt Creator to user MSVC2015?

Tags: c++, windows-8, qt-creator

I've install Qt 5.8 SDK for Windows using Online Qt installer from official QT site with supporting MSVC2013 x64 and MSVC2015 x64. Because `webenginewidgets` doesnt support MinGW compiler.
But I have no compiler selected in build environments configurcation window in QTCreator. But I have installed alot of MSVC including MSVC2015_64 and MSVC2015_32. What I need to set up in this options to have ability to compile programs from QTCreator?
[image]

Comment: The compilers have to be detected automatically. If they're not, then you have to add them manually. Check this out: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html

Comment: Btw, I use 10 versions of Qt Creator together, but never had to install them like this from the Qt website. What I would do, is download their sources, compile the ones I need, and then add them to Qt Creator. Here's a tutorial on how to compile Qt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932315/how-to-compile-qt-5-under-windows-or-linux-32-or-64-bit-static-or-dynamic-on-v

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't so much experience in cpp environment. Even if I have  projects using C++, understanding all things around C++ is hell for me. UPD: Also I don't know, on which platform application will be running, because I have no problems with Qt on Linux, but Windows...

Answer (score 2):

1. install visual c++ build tools 2015, but uncheck any SDK within the installer.
2. install windows SDK 10 from microsoft website.
3. install qt 5.8 (be sure to check msvc2015 32-bit or 64-bit, and debugger tool might be important...)