# stuck on compiling QDoc for building qt5 on windows

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5

Basically, I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932315/how-to-compile-qt-5-under-windows-or-linux-32-or-64-bit-static-or-dynamic-on-v) to build qt5, after running configure commands, it prompted:

```
WARNING: QDOC will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means theat you cannot build the Qt ducomentation.
...
On Windows, you must set LLVN_INSTALL_DIR to the installation path.
```

so I setup a environment variable LLVM_INSTALL_DIR following this [page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoc-guide-clang.html)(I got LLVM [here](https://llvm.org/builds/)), when I enter `set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR` in the command promp, it printed out`LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=D:\LLVM`. So I am assured that LLVM has been properly installed. Who can help me taking this warning away(My IDE is Visual Studio 2019)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by building the source downloaded from qt's MaintenanceTool